# STEP 2018 Q2: Solution explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

The problem I am looking at is [image: problem 12]

I have had no issues doing this question by rearanging the lefthand and right hand side to get two gradients, however, this is not the intended method of answering this question. It is given by

[image: answer]

I understand how $Y$ is parameterised but I can't seem to figure out how $X$ is.  The  output in $X$ is not a function of the input, but rather, only dependent on $t$. I do not understand how was the $x$ value for $X$ just assigned to it as being this parameterization. Could somebody help me understand the answer above?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply geometry of similar right triangles.  The big right triangle has base $x_2 - x_1$.  At the left endpoint $x = x_1$, the value of the function is $f(x_1)$; similarly, at the right endpoint, the value of the function is $f(x_2)$.  So the height of the triangle is the difference in these values, $f(x_2) - f(x_1)$.

**However, you are quite understandably confused because the way the diagram is labeled is not consistent with the algebraic definition.**  Moreover, the choice of notation is somewhat unfortunate.

In the diagram, the parameter $t \in [0,1]$ represents the proportion along the base (as measured from the left endpoint) at which the point $x$ lies.  That is to say, for $$x(t) = x_1 + t(x_2 - x_1) = (1-t)x_1 + t x_2,$$ the choice $t = 0$ gives us $x = x_1$, and the choice $t = 1$ gives us $x = x_2$.  The value of the function at $x(t)$ is simply $y = f(x(t)) = f((1-t)x_1 + t x_2)$, but the height $h(t)$ of the triangle at this point, by similarity of triangles, satisfies $$\frac{h(t)}{t(x_2 - x_1)} = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1},$$ or $$h(t) = t(f(x_2) - f(x_1)).$$  Consequently, the $y$-value of this point is given by $$h(t) + f(x_1) = (1-t)f(x_1) + t f(x_2).$$

This is how the **diagram** is labeled.  The formula given, $$t f(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2) \le f(t x_1 + (1-t) x_2),$$ is reversed with respect to the value of $t$.  Indeed, in the formula, when $t = 0$, we get $f(x_2) \le f(x_2)$, whereas this choice of $t$ in the diagram corresponds to $f(x_1)$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer @heropup. I wanted to ask you, in the answer diagram, do you think they wrote the $x$ coordinate for $X$ to then make a function if it in the $y$ coordinate (which if yes I still do not understand how one can derive the equation of the line from there) or was it made just to construct the similar triangles?

Comment: @MathsWizzard I disregarded the equations on the right hand side of the diagram, because they are incorrect relative to the labeling of the figure on the left.  If we follow the labeling of the figure, those points should read $$X = \left(x_1 + t(x_2 - x_1), f(x_1) + t(f(x_2) - f(x_1)) \right), \\ Y = \left(x_1 + t(x_2 - x_1), f(x_1 + t(x_2 - x_1))\right),$$ or $$X = \left(x_2 - (1-t)(x_2 - x_1), f(x_2) - (1-t)(f(x_2) - f(x_1)) \right), \\ Y = \left(x_2 - (1-t)(x_2 - x_1), f(x_2 - (1-t)(x_2 - x_1)) \right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x_{2} - t(x_{2}-x_{1})$ is a *weighted average* between $x_{2}$ and $x_{1}$, a concept that will be very prevalent in this definition. (It is called a weighted average because as the weight, $t$, varies from $0$ to $1$, you move from $x_{2}$ to $x_{1}$). Note that $x$ is the point that is the weighted average of $f(x_{2})$ and $f(x_{1})$, so it is on the line joining the two points, and $y$ is the point on the graph of $f(x)$ given by $x = x_{2} - t(x_{2}-x_{1})$. Then, this definition says that $y$ is always above $x$, which makes sense because for a function to be concave it should be "above" a line joining any $2$ of its points.

The definition for a convex function is similar, but in that case $x$ lies below $y$.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are happy with how the $x$-coordinate is constructed since it is the same for $X$ and for $Y$ - in particular, at $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, the value $(1-t)x_1+x_2$ goes linearly from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

The $y$-coordinate of $Y$ is constructed in exactly the same way: as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, the value $(1-t)f(x_1)+tf(x_2)$ goes from $f(x_1)$ to $f(x_2)$. It might be instructive to replace $f(x_i)$ by $y_i$ in these equations to see that they are really the same.

If you want to see exactly how the $y$-coordinate of $Y$ depends on the $x$-coordinate, let $x=(1-t)x_1+tx_2=x_1+t(x_2-x_1)$, and then
\begin{align*}
y=(1-t)f(x_1)+tf(x_2)&=\left( 1-\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} \right)f(x_1)+\left( \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)f(x_2) \\
&=\left( \frac{x-x_2}{x_1-x_2}\right)f(x_1)+\left( \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)f(x_2)
\end{align*}

If you want to convince yourself that this is correct, try writing out the general linear equation $y=ax+b$ and solving the simultaneous equations you get by specifying that this line passes through $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$. Then you will be able to rearrange to the equation above.

As a final tip: the equation $y=ax+b$ is not always the **best** general linear equation to write down. In this scenario, the best linear equation to write down would be $y=a(x-x_1)+b(x-x_2)$, because the form of this equation makes the simultaneous equations very easy to solve! In general remember that choose a nice form for your general equation can simplify things a lot.

Comment: Hi @George R, I have a few questions. 1) Aren't $x_1$ and $x_2$ switched in your answer? 2) I fail to see what you mean by solving the simultaneous equations. What do we aim to eliminate?